# I cannot forward the video

Tags: javascript, html, django, video.js

I have created a web application using Django and stored videos in the static file. I loaded the static files onto the HTML page and used video.js as the video player.

I am playing a video in Chrome and Edge, but it does not allow me to fast-forward. When I try to fast forward, the video restarts from the beginning.

However, when playing the video in Firefox and Safari, I can fast forward without any issues, but when the video ends and returns to view again, it can be skipped forward.

I would like to know why I cannot fast forward in Chrome or Edge and how to fix this issue.

Comment: This is the code related to the project that I previously posted a question about.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75577426/the-progress-bar-cannot-be-dragged-forward-to-skip-ahead